# Inserting JSON Data into Database Table

Tags: json, symfony

Is something like in the link below possible in Symfony2 ?

http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/12/how-to-insert-json-data-into-mysql-php.html

My plan is to create a CRON Job that would hit a specific route which will execute logic in a controller that would persist json data into a database table at a set time every day.

So basically, I would grab the JSON file, extract the values I want and store them in variables, then persist them to a database table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using doctrine, you can simply do:

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$entity = new Entity();

$entity->setName($data['personal']['name']);
$entity->setGender($data['personal']['gender']);
```

Then you just need to use the entitymanager, to persist it depending on you context:

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```